# Python - Unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python, list

I have this code snippet where it returns the index of the lowest integer in a list

```
for x in range(0,len(points)):
    minVal = min(range(len(pathValue)), key=pathValue.__getitem__)
    if visited[x] != "T": visited[minVal]= "T"
```

points visited and pathValue are all lists and contains the following:

```
points = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
visited = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
pathValue = [9, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However when I compile the program it always points an error to this line

```
 minVal = min(range(len(pathValue)), key=pathValue.__getitem__)
```

and says

```
Unorderable types: str() < int()
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: it would be better if you copy paste the `pathvalue` list from a command prompt. even `pathValue = ['9', 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`, this will show you the error you are getting

Comment: @manojprashantk: it is not the first element in the list; in that case the `str()` and `int()` values in the error message would be reversed. But yes, there is a string object in the list.

Comment: yes i just made an example out there and thanks for specifying what happens if the first element is a string :)

Answer (score 0):

Not all values in `pathValue` are integers. You have *at least* one string object in that list.

If there are only integers in `pathValue`, your expression works:

```
>>> pathValue = [9, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> min(range(len(pathValue)), key=pathValue.__getitem__)
2
```

But add a string, and you get your specific error:

```
>>> pathValue = [9, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'foo']
>>> min(range(len(pathValue)), key=pathValue.__getitem__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Make *absolutely* sure your `pathValue` list only contains integers.

Note that I'd use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) here instead of `range()` and `pathValue.__getitem__`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

minVal = min(enumerate(pathValue), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

This too retrieves the index of the minimum value, provided there are only integers in the input list, of course.